# Empty System Message Popup in Admin

Tags: admin-panel, magento2.4.4

When logging in to admin, we have a empty message popup:

[image: empty message]

HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="message-system-inner" data-bind="outerClick: fixLoaderHeight.bind($data, true)">
        <div class="message-system-short">
            <button class="message-system-action-dropdown" data-bind="toggleCollapsible">
                <span>
                    <!-- ko i18n: 'System Messages' --><span>System Messages</span><!-- /ko -->:
                    <!-- ko text: totalRecords -->1<!-- /ko -->
                </span>
            </button>
            <!-- ko if: rows[0] --><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        <div class="message-system-collapsible">
            <ul class="message-system-list">
                <!-- ko repeat: {foreach: rows, item: '$row'} --><!-- /ko -->
            </ul>
            <!-- ko if: isAllowed --><div class="message-system-summary">
                <a class="action__message-log" href="#" data-bind="text: dismissAllText, click: dismissAll">Dismiss All Completed Tasks</a>
                <a class="action__message-log" data-bind="attr: {
                        href: link
                    }, text: linkText" href="xxx">Bulk Actions Log</a>
            </div><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

The `admin_system_message` table is empty:

```
> select * from admin_system_messages;
Empty set (0.001 sec)
```

Also we marked all notifications (system -> notifications) as read.

- Does anybody see the same problem?
- How can this be debugged further?

Comment: i have this issue too. Any solution yet?

Comment: No, we did not yet found a solution. Did you dig deeper? Which modules do you have installed? Maybe it comes from a module ...

Comment: I've noticed the bulk actioons log doesn't load either..